# Detect navigator inside WebExtension's manifest.json

Tags: if-statement, detection, firefox-addon-webextensions, navigator, manifest.json

I am currently working on a WebExtension and I have a small problem. On my Firefox browser I'm able to import and run my work without any error/warning. However with Google Chrome I have a big warning about a feature not implemented (the `browser_style` property of `manifest.json` key `options_ui`).

I'd like to create something like an if statement based on the navigator name to not set this property on Chrome but keep it on Firefox.

Here is the part of my `manifest.json`:

```
"options_ui": {                                                                                                                                                                    
"page": "contents/settings.html",                                                                                                                                              
"browser_style": true                                                                                                                                                       
},
```

And here is what I'd like to have (not working):

```
"options_ui": {                                                                                                                                                                    
"page": "contents/settings.html",
if (options_ui.browser_style) {                                                                                                                          
    "browser_style": true      
    }                                                                                                                                                 
},
```

Any ideas on how to create a condition like this in a `manifest.json` file?

Comment: JSON is for static data storage and does not have conditionals. You will need separate files.

Answer (score 0):

As Daniel Herr [implied in a comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46253384/detect-navigator-inside-manifest-json-with-webextensions#comment79476370_46253384), the *manifest.json* file is straight JSON formatted data. JSON has no capability to run code. There is no possibility to dynamically define properties within your *manifest.json* file. You have 2 options:

1. Live with the warning(s).
   Both Chrome and Firefox have valid properties defined for *manifest.json* files which the other does not support. Both show warnings when there are unsupported properties. These are *only* warnings and do not cause the browser to prevent the extension from running. Chrome prominently shows these in *chrome://extensions/*. Firefox shows them in the [Browser Console](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Tools/Browser_Console) (Ctrl-Shift-J, or Cmd-Shift-J on OSX).
2. Have a separate *manifest.json* file per browser.
   This adds some complexity to your build/development process, but will allow you to eliminate these warnings in each browser.

Note: Even if you don't submit different *manifest.json* files to Google (Chrome Web Store - Extensions) and Mozilla (AMO), by the time the extension package is distributed to the user, the *manifest.json* files and other contents of the extension package will be different, as the process of going from submission to distribution results in that file being modified and/or additional files being added to the extension package.

Comment: Okay, so there is a tricks with the filename ? like "manifest.chrome.json" and "manifest.firefox.json" ? Or I have to create two directory ? like "my_extension_chrome" and "my_extension_firefox" ?

Comment: @Xjames56X There are no tricks with the file name. You will need to handle it in some other manner. However, you would only need to do so when preparing the package for submission to Google/Mozilla (assuming you can live with the warning during most of your development). This could be automated to use an appropriately filtered version of the manifest.json for each.

Comment: Thanks. Too bad, the purpose of webExtensions is to be standardized, right ?